# The scheduler failed to assign job to the runner, please try again or contact system administrator

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I'm trying to deploy a gitlab instance and two runners in a different host. When I execute a pipeline from the GUI I have the message "The scheduler failed to assign job to the runner, please try again or contact system administrator"
I have probed with two runners: a shell runner and a docker runner. The runner is well selected using the tags in yml file, but jobs are never executed
Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be due to variables used within rules.
Below is the error case observed:

```
rules :
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  variables:
    PROJECT_ID: 26
```

Fix - updated the variable assignment with quotes (for PROJECT_ID)

```
rules :
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  variables:
    PROJECT_ID: "26"
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, our gitlab upgraded, this error only occur in one repository, I think this is a bug of gitlab, or when upgrading, the data of that repository is corrputed somehow.

Comment: I've had the same issue only in one repository too after migrating GitLab to another server from backup. Unfortunately I didn't backup secrets so I had to reset CI variables and other stuff, but it didn't help. My solution was to export this project, rename the old one and import it again. After that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had these 2 variables in my CI yaml file

```
  # TF_VAR_task_cpu: 256
  # TF_VAR_task_memory: 512
```

removing them solved the issue
Runner version: gitlab-runner 14.0.1